# linear quantile mixed model [R] lqmm - package: Error in f(arg, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r, mixed-models, quantile

I want to compute linear quantile mixed models but I always get the following error

```
Error in f(arg, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

To reproduce please download the dataset and import it:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/79415744/mixedModelDataSet.txt

```
stackoverflow <- read.table("mixedModelDataSet.txt",  sep="\t", header = TRUE ) # import
```

then try to compute the model:

```
require("lqmm")
stack15 <- lqmm(gsDeviationMio ~ aoi, random =  ~ 1, group = vpName, data = stackoverflow, tau = 0.15)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Computing non quantile mixed models works:

```
stackLme <- lme(gsDeviationMio ~ aoi, random =  ~ 1|vpName, data = stackoverflow)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Best,
Florian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer of Marco Geraci (author of lqmm)

There's a problem with the scale of the response. Also, the 'gs' algorithm seems to have some issues with this dataset. Try the following

```
stackoverflow$y <- scale(stackoverflow$gsDeviationMio, center = T, scale = T)

lqmm(y ~ aoi, random =  ~ 1, group = vpName, data = stackoverflow, tau = 0.15, control = lqmmControl(method = "df", UP_max_iter = 200))
```